# How to display the result of 'netstat' command pagewise?

Tags: windows, command

netstat command is giving me a long list. I would like to see the results of `netstat -noa` pagewise on windows command prompt. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe the output through the `more` tool:

```
netstat -noa | more
```

This will paginate the results for you, you can press:

- <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to progress an entire page
- <kbd>RETURN</kbd> to progress a single line

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with storing the result in a text file, this might come in handy

```
C:\Documents>netstat -noa > text.txt
C:\Documents>more < text.txt
```

Comment: this is also useful, but @Rob's answer was the one I was looking for.